# Como listar itens por usuário logado no asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma aplicação que gerencia **Cursos** e estou com o seguinte problema, o **aluno** faz sua **inscrição** em *cursos*, só que quando o **aluno** acessa a página onde lista os cursos que ele está inscrito, essa **lista também está listando os cursos de outros alunos**, e **não somente** o do aluno que está **logado**.

**Tentei fazer assim**

Minha `Action` do controller `Curso`

```
public ActionResult MeusCursos()
    {
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno != null)
            return View("MeusCursos", db.Cursos.ToList());

        return View();

    }
```

`Post`

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MeusCursos(int id)
    {
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno != null)
            return View("MeusCursos", db.Cursos.ToList());

        var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
        if (curso == null)
            return View("MeusCursos");


        return View(db.Cursos.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto está obviamente errado:

```
Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
if (aluno != null)
    return View("MeusCursos", db.Cursos.ToList());
```

Aqui:

```
db.Cursos.ToList()
```

Você está trazendo todos os cursos. Se o objetivo é listar apenas os cursos do aluno, use as propriedades de navegação de aluno. Ou seja:

```
Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
if (aluno != null)
    return View("MeusCursos", aluno.AlunoCursos.Select(ac => ac.Curso).ToList());
```

O método com `[HttpPost]` não é necessário porque é apenas uma listagem. Não existe persistência de dados para esta *Action*.

Comment: Apenar para complementar. `HttpGet` para requisitar consulta de dados, `HttpPost` para requisitar adição/criação de dados, `HttpPut` para requisitar atualização de dados e `HttpDelete` para requisitar exclusão de dados.